# Sorting Array according to ArrayList using comparator

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, design-patterns, collections

I'm trying to sort an Array (Object hits[]) that stores Objects and I need to be sorted with the exact order (asceding, descending) as in ArrayList which is already sorted. These two are not related in any way.

I have seen similar problems, with the difference that you sort the ArrayList using the order in the Array. But I want the opposite.
I tried to convert the ArrayList to simple Array and go from there, so the problem becomes "sorting array using another array" but that didn't really helped me since I want "sorting array of Objects using another array".

```
Arrays.sort(hits, new Comparator<ArrayList<Double>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ArrayList<Double> c1, ArrayList<Double> c2) {
              return Double.compare(c1.get(0), c2.get(0));
        }
    });
```

I want something in the vein of the code above, which is giving me the error "not applicable" with the types I'm currently using as arguments.

Comment: the question is not clear. what is the type of the items in the array? is it `Double`? you want to sort the array to match the order of items in the list?

Comment: *as in ArrayList which is already sorted.* Meaning same order as in another array list ?

Comment: I can’t understand the question either, maybe you could add an example to help us understand what you want?

Comment: @SharonbenAsher The items in the array are not Double. It's an array of Objects. The Object can be anything like Cars[] array = new Cars[] and yes I want to sort this to match the order in ArrayList<Double>

Comment: you cannot sort an array of `Object`s by anything other than `Object`'s properties

Comment: Please provide some sample data so we can understand your question. Currently, it is not clear how a list of double can be related to an array of object.

Answer (score 1):

A `Comparator` is not defined in terms of the `Collection` is going to operate over; but in terms of the *elements* is going to operate on.

So, your `Comparator` needs to be something like `Comparator<Double>` rather than `Comparator<ArrayList<Double>>`, then you can use it to sort any `Collection` including arrays indistinctly.

The following is a working demo of how a the SAME `Comparator` is used indistinctly to sort a `List` of custom objects and also to sort an array of the same custom objects:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class SortArrayLists {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Comparator<MyObject> comparator = Comparator.comparingDouble(MyObject::getDoubleValue);     
        
        MyObject[] array = new MyObject[] {
                new MyObject(55),
                new MyObject(17.3),
                new MyObject(2.43),
                new MyObject(375),
                new MyObject(100),
                new MyObject(255)
        };
        List<MyObject> list = Arrays.asList(array);
        list.sort(comparator);
        Arrays.sort(array, comparator);

        list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        Arrays.stream(array).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    static class MyObject {
        private double doubleValue;

        public MyObject(double doubleValue) {
            this.doubleValue = doubleValue;
        }

        public double getDoubleValue() {
            return doubleValue;
        }
        
        public String toString() {
            return doubleValue + "";
        }
    }
}
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a56206925)

Hope this helps.